# How to use Scanner.nextLine()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I use this code to input something in the String variable n, after I type what is asked, I don't want the program to print what I typed.

The code:

String n= Scanner.nextLine();

I feel is something you type after Scanner. , but I don't know what is it.

EDITED:
Thanks for answer, but I don't know how to Close the Scanner.
Here is the program...:

My program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String n;
        Scanner bananas=new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("First Digit: ");
        n=bananas.nextLine();
    }
}
```

When I run the program, on the screen appears: "First Digit:",
then type, let's say I type "apple", the String n will be equals to
"apple", it's ok, that is what I want, what I don't like is that the
program prints on the screen the String n, I didn't want the program
to do that, this is what happens:

First Digit: 
apples

What I want I the program to print is just:
"First Digit: ", without showing what I typed, just keep it.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Like you want to clear the console/what you typed? Or you're typing your answer and you're saying `Scanner.nextLine()` is repeating it on the another line and want to delete that?

Comment: Answer by @MaxMega will solve your issue

Comment: Firslty, Scanner Scanner=new Scanner(System.in); is not right
While doing this.. keep name of the object different from the class name. It can be like 'Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);'

Comment: its written below.. you can do it like bananas.close(); after taking input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to instantiate the Scanner, like so:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  //if you want to read from the console
```

Then, you can receive your input.

```
String n = scanner.nextLine();
```

Make sure you close your scanner when you don't need it anymore:

```
scanner.close();
```

Comment: How to close the scanner?, what I want is the program to keep the new value of n without printing it. Just that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing tricky about it. You can do it like below and still your variable will hold your desired value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String n;
        Scanner bananas=new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("First Digit: ");
        n=bananas.nextLine();        // once you are done with input
        bananas.close();
    }
}
```

Even if you don't close scanner it won't make any difference as far as your code execution is concerned. Only a warning some where in your class will arise which doesn;t really affect your code. But still it is better to close the scanner once you are done with it. Its a good practice.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what I want is the program to hide instead of printing it on the screen below the "First Digit:"... I want to input without looking at it... Like when you type a password. Thanks.

Comment: you should better see this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623215/simple-java-scanner-issue